# What is the work done in isobaric expansion?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

I'm really confused now... I thought the equation was $ W = \int PdV = P\Delta V $ since P is a constant and can be taken outside of the integral. But on the other hand, $ P = \frac{NkT}{V} $, so if I use that substitution, I get a different answer.
I don't think the solution for [problem 5.c (page 12) here](http://physics.fsu.edu/QualifyingExam/qualf07-solutions.pdf) is right ... But now I don't even know +.+ .. Could someone please tell me which way is right?

Comment: The problem states that the expansion is _isothermal_ not _isobaric_.  Therefore, you cannot take $P$ out of the integral.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *since P is a constant and can be taken outside of the integral*

There is no reason whatsoever why $p$ should be a constant, unless specified so; in particular, in your exercise the task is to find a solution for isothermal transformations. For gases and fluids $p$ is a function of the volume and other variables as well, therefore the equation becomes
$$
W = \int_{\gamma}dV\,p(V).
$$
Also notice that in general the work done by the pressure does depend on the path $\gamma$ you follow, namely on the type of transformation you have, since on that depends the way the pressure changes with the volume. This is often stated staying that $W$ is not an exact differential. In case of an ideal gas $p\sim V^{-1}$ and hence you have a logarithmic dependence for the work done, which is the correct result.

Comment: ah geez, I saw "free expansion" and for some reason thought P is constant .... * * facepalm * * ___ ___ ... Thank you for explaining.